# Error passing challenge "Deploy a Lightning web component with a reset button"

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, vs-code, salesfoce

I wrote the following code and it is working fine in my playground but get this error in passing challenge.

***We can't find 'lightning-input' in accountFinder.html.***

**accountFinder.Html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-input
        type="Number"
        formatter= "currency"
        label="Annual Revenue"
        value={annualRevenue}
        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button
        label="Reset"
        onclick={reset}>
    </lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
```

**accountFinder.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class AccountSearch extends LightningElement {
    annualRevenue = null;
    handleChange(event) {
        this.annualRevenue = event.detail.value;
    }
    reset() {
        this.annualRevenue = null;
    }
}
```

**accountFinder.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**Trailhead**
[image: Error in Challenge]

I've tried this new 2 new playground but unable to pass the challenge. I think I'm making some silly mistake. can anyone help me to pass this challenge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create the ```LWC Visualforce Devs app page```?

Comment: yes, also set defaultusername=lwc_for_vf_devs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `number` not `Number` and remove space before  `"currency"`.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-input
            type="number"
            formatter="currency"
            label="Annual Revenue"
            value={annualRevenue}
            onchange={handleChange}>
        </lightning-input>
        <lightning-button
            label="Reset"
            onclick={reset}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>    
</template>
```

Comment: Hey **Klecool**, 
Thanks for the solution. it works.  Trailhead uses 'Number' that's why I was writing the same. _Thank you_ again for help

Comment: Now they fixed the Issue and it accepts type="Number" to pass this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

### in **accountFinder.js**

you need to change export class in :
export default class **accountFinder**  // not *AccountSearch*

Comment: Names for default exports don't matter.